# R.java is not generated or variable cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, android-listview, r.java-file

ive got XML player_layout.xml with code like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="30dp"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<ListView
    android:id="@id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:entries="@strings/sections" >
</ListView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

now when im trying to build my project, im using this layout here:

```
public class PlayerListViewActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.player_layout);

    //* *EDIT* * 
    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    listview.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.i("HelloListView", "You clicked Item: " + id + " at position:" + position);

}
}
```

when im trying to build my project, R.java file is not generating or when i clean project variables R.layout.player_layout and R.id.listView1 "cannot be resolved etc"

in my opinion thats means there is an error in player_layout.xml, but i cant figure out where

thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

im sure now that an error is here:

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listView1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:entries="@strings/sections" >
</ListView>
```

there was missing `+` between `@` and `id`. however it isnt enough to correct that. still dont know where is other mistake... if everything here is okey maybe `@strings/sections` tab is incorrect. 
it looks like :

```
<string-array name="sections">
    <item >1st</item>
    <item >2nd</item>
    <item >3rd</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: got it! `@strings` must be replaced with `@array`, ty Tarsem for trying help

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you saved your xml file. I spent an hour trying to figure out the same problem, and that was my fix.